# Convert MySQL Query with variables to Postgres Query

Tags: mysql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a MySQL query that works fine:

```
SELECT MAX(count) as `max_streak`
FROM (
     SELECT x.*, 
     IF(DATEDIFF(@prev, login_at) = 1, @count:= @count + 1, @count:=1) as `count`,@prev := login_at
     FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(login_at)) as login_at FROM login_histories WHERE user_id = ?) x,
        (SELECT @count := 1, @prev := null) a
     ORDER BY login_at desc) a
```

But I need to convert this to work with our new Postgres database, and am having struggles with doing so.

I was able to come up with this (which does not work):

```
SELECT MAX(count) as max_streak
    FROM (
         SELECT x.*, 
         CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(@prev, login_at) = 1 THEN SET @count = @count + 1 ELSE SET @count = 1 END as count, @prev = login_at
         FROM
            (SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(login_at)) as login_at FROM login_histories WHERE user_id = ?) x,
            (SELECT @count = @count + 1, @prev = null) a
         ORDER BY login_at desc) a
```

I tried using `SET` to see if that would fix it, but error keeps ending up at the end `SELECT @count = @count + 1, @prev = null)`

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  column "count" does not exist
LINE 7:                     (SELECT @count = @count + 1, @prev = nul...
                                     ^
```

Is there something i'm missing here that someone can point me in the right direction please?

Comment: What does it do? The hack with variables can typically be replaced with modern window functions (even on MySQL). And datediff can be replcated with `login_at - ...`

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Forget about existing query and create new one from the same beginning. PostgreSQL supports window functions and does not need in the tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo of the gaps-and-islands type of query. I'm using MySQL 8.0, but the solution uses standard window functions so it should work in any modern SQL database.

```
mysql> select * from login_histories;
+---------------------+---------+
| login_at            | user_id |
+---------------------+---------+
| 2022-08-01 00:00:00 |       1 |
| 2022-08-02 00:00:00 |       1 |
| 2022-08-03 00:00:00 |       1 |
| 2022-08-04 00:00:00 |       1 |
| 2022-08-06 00:00:00 |       1 |
| 2022-08-07 00:00:00 |       1 |
| 2022-08-08 00:00:00 |       1 |
| 2022-08-10 00:00:00 |       1 |
| 2022-08-11 00:00:00 |       1 |
+---------------------+---------+
```

Notice there are three spans of consecutive days.

```
select max(count) as maxcount
from (
  select day_online, count(*) as count
  from (
    select
      date_sub(login_at, interval dense_rank() over (partition by user_id order by login_at)-1 day) as day_online
    from login_histories
  ) as t
  group by day_online
) as t2;

+----------+
| maxcount |
+----------+
|        4 |
+----------+
```

I'll go through it step by step to illustrate.

The window function DENSE_RANK() ranks the rows consecutively. If we subtract that rank from the date in the first span of days, we get the very first date. But when there's a break in the consecutive dates, the rank gets off by at least one. So the subtraction results in a distinct date, not the original start date. Then another gap causes the difference to be greater, and so on.

```
select
  login_at,
  dense_rank() over (partition by user_id order by login_at)-1 as denserank,
  date_sub(login_at, interval dense_rank() over (partition by user_id order by login_at)-1 day) as day_online
from login_histories;

+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| login_at            | denserank | day_online          |
+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 2022-08-01 00:00:00 |         0 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 |
| 2022-08-02 00:00:00 |         1 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 |
| 2022-08-03 00:00:00 |         2 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 |
| 2022-08-04 00:00:00 |         3 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 |
| 2022-08-06 00:00:00 |         4 | 2022-08-02 00:00:00 |
| 2022-08-07 00:00:00 |         5 | 2022-08-02 00:00:00 |
| 2022-08-08 00:00:00 |         6 | 2022-08-02 00:00:00 |
| 2022-08-10 00:00:00 |         7 | 2022-08-03 00:00:00 |
| 2022-08-11 00:00:00 |         8 | 2022-08-03 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

This groups the rows into the groups of consecutive dates. The dates in the third column have no meaning, they are only meant to be distinct for each group.

Grouping by these distinct values, we can count the number of rows in each group.

```
select day_online, count(*) as count
from ( 
  select
    date_sub(login_at, interval dense_rank() over (partition by user_id order by login_at)-1 day) as day_online
  from login_histories
) as t 
group by day_online;

+---------------------+-------+
| day_online          | count |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2022-08-01 00:00:00 |     4 |
| 2022-08-02 00:00:00 |     3 |
| 2022-08-03 00:00:00 |     2 |
+---------------------+-------+
```

Then just take the MAX() of that count value.

In my demo, I was only storing dates rounded off, and I only had one user_id value. I'll leave it to you to adapt this to your case, where you may have different times and user_id's.